# Creating a paperlike folded view in android

Tags: android, textview

[image: folded corner]

This is what i want to make for my textview. I have a 9 patch image [image: here]. But i have no idea how can i convert this png image into the folded corner background for the textview.Many of you may have faced this problem and came up with a solution. So, please share how did you solved yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres the solution for you:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/yourTextViewWidget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_9_patch_image"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:text="Testing News" />
```

Let me expalain here: Setting the 9 patch image as the background of the textview and putting the padding to the textview will create the above image like background for your textview.